# How to XOR bytes in memory in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory, xor

I need a function which takes a start address as first parameter and a size as second and it should xor that range in memory at runtime. How can I accomplish that?

My naive approach was this:

```
void XorMemory(DWORD StartAddress, DWORD dwSize)
{
    DWORD *Start = &StartAddress;
    DWORD size = StartAddress + dwSize;
    DWORD *End = &size;

    while(*Start < *End)
    {
        *Start++ ^= 0x83;
    }

}
```

But it fails when it needs to reverse the operation. How to fix it?

Comment: "It fails." *What* fails? `DWORD StartAddress` is not an address, it is a value. Please show the calling code too, the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Besides the obvious wrong methods for both passing, and using, `StartAddress`, and the madness of `&size`, are you trying to xor each *byte*, or a sequence of `DWORD`s?, The code implies the latter, but that would be pretty pathetic xor-masking, as only 1/4 of the memory would actually be masked.

Comment: For your information, this isn't encryption at all. If you know this already, you might want to rephrase your title.

Answer (score 0):

```
void EncryptDecrypt(DWORD StartAddress, DWORD dwSize)
{
    BYTE * t = (BYTE *)StartAddress;
    for ( DWORD i = 0; i < dwSize; i++ )
        t[i] ^= 0x83;
}
```

But it is not good idea to define `StartAddress` as `DWORD`. It is better to be `BYTE *` or even `void *`.

Comment: What's wrong with the standard type `unsigned char`? That is exactly a byte. Using proprietary types witout reason is in general bad design. And the cast invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Although `WinDef.h` and maybe others have `typedef unsigned char BYTE;`, using `unsigned char` is one step close to portability.

Comment: @Olaf I agree with `unsigned char` but when `DWORD` is defined, I assume that `BYTE` is also defined (probably Win32 project).

Comment: @i486: Not on tany system I program. If you need ne 32 bit type, use the standard `uint32_t` (resp. its signed counterpart). But I well understand if oen works with an outdated compiler which does not support modern C, one has to use such quirks. The alternative is of course to move on. C99 is now 17 years old, even the current version is 5 years old already.